# Hide the page titles of some content types

Tags: nodes, theming

I found following code on this website http://codekarate.com/content/hiding-page-titles-specific-node-types-drupal-6 to hide the page titles of some content types.

Can some one help me rewrite this for drupal 7 ??

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['original_title'] = $vars['title'];
  if (!empty($vars['node']) && in_array($vars['node']->type, array('NODETYPE'))) {
    $vars['title'] = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you alteady try it? Looks like ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to let you know that there is a module that does this [Exclude Node Tittle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99vjt.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I tried that but that does not provide any option to remove title for selected content types. Please advise if that allows ?

Comment: @Fahad it's right in the first paragraph of the description: "Also provides the option to hide all titles of a certain Content type."

Comment: @Fahad it does allow you to, see picture.

Comment: @Fahad For example: In the above picture, if you want to have the title show up in Basic Page, you have to **uncheck mark** the exclude from full view and teaser, under Basic Page.

Answer (score 1):

The code should work just fine in Drupal 7. But note that it only works on node pages (where the URL is `node/[nid]`) and does not work on lists of teases make with Views or the default Drupal frontpage.

I made a small modification to the code below using 'page' and 'article' as example content types instead of `NODETYPE`.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['original_title'] = $vars['title'];
  if (!empty($vars['node']) && in_array($vars['node']->type, array('article', 'page'))) {
    $vars['title'] = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use exclude_node_title you can do this:

on your theme edit the template.php and add/modify this hook:

```
function YORTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 $vars['show_title'] = TRUE;
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    if ($vars['node']->type == 'YOURTYPE') {
      $vars['show_title'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

and on your page.tpl look for the part where the title is shown and use the show_title variable in this way:

```
<?php if ( ($title) && ($show_title) ): ?>
  <h1 id="page-title">
    <?php print $title; ?>
  </h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```